# Git Aborting with "git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories"

Tags: git

I have made a mess of my Git on my DigitalOcean server.  Pycharm saves conflicted all the Git data.

I tried to wipeout the .git on the Server and start over.  But I obviously cant do a clone and overwrite all my Django/server settings.

I can not do things like "git pull" or "git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories."

It gets an "Aborting" error.

What is the proper way to start over and overwrite or re-synch the data?  Should I just skip the Git and use the Pycharm?  (I am basically the only one working on the code.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Following [How To Use Git Effectively](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-effectively), you can try and recreate your Git repository, where your sources are (once you have fixed said sources)

After a `git init .`; `git add .` and a commit, PyCharm should be able to re-import that Git repository in its projects.

The [OP diogenes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6312979/diogenes) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59042390/git-aborting-with-git-pull-origin-master-allow-unrelated-histories/59044701?noredirect=1#comment105342233_59044701):

> I should just let Pycharm do its thing.
>   Lots of time I just use the Git as a backup file.

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Comment: a bit.  I should just let Pycharm do its thing.  Lots of time I just use the Git as a backup file.  thanks.